# Unit testing a module in another file in racket

Tags: module, racket

I'm trying to unit test the code i've written in racket and i don't want to have to provide each and every function singularly, so i've written it all in a module:

```lisp
(module avl_tree racket 
    (provide all-defined-out)
    (define (is_tree? tree)
        ; does whatever)

    ; so on with other code
)
```

This is in the file `avl_tree.rkt`.

I'm trying to unit test this in another file in the same directory, avl_tree_testing, which looks like this:

```lisp
#lang racket
(require rackunit)
(require "avl_tree.rkt")

(is_tree? '(5 (1 null null) (9 (6 null null) (10 null null))))
```

However, no matter what I do, I get this error:

```
<filepath>\avl_tree\avl_tree_testing.rkt:5:1: is_tree?: unbound identifier
  in: is_tree?Racket
```

I've tried prefixing is_tree? with the name of the module `avl_tree:is_tree?` but that's gotten me nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each source file in Racket is implicitly a module; the `module` form creates [*submodules*](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Module_Syntax.html#%28part._submodules%29) which can be required with `submod`:

```lisp
(require (submod "avl_tree.rkt" avl_tree))
```

You also need to use [`(all-defined-out)`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._all-defined-out%29%29) in the `provide` form; note the parens.

In your example then, you want to drop the `module` and just keep its body:

```lisp
#lang racket/base
;;; avl_tree.rkt

(provide (all-defined-out))

(define (is-tree? tree)
  ; does whatever)
  
  ; so on with other code
  )
```

With this, `(require "avl_tree.rkt")` will work as you expected.

(Also note using [idiomatic kebab-case](https://docs.racket-lang.org/style/Textual_Matters.html#%28part._names%29); `is-tree?` not `is_tree?`. Stick with the conventions and other people will be much happier reading your code. Just plain `tree?` might be even better; the question mark implies the `is-` part. Compare to standard functions like `string?` or `number?`)

---

Additionally, you can add tests to the same file as the code you're testing with no loss in efficiency by using the [`test` submodule](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Module_Syntax.html#%28part._main-and-test%29), which is automatically run by DrRacket's Run command (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>) or by the [`raco test` command line tool](https://docs.racket-lang.org/raco/test.html). The key here is to use [`module+`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/module.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._module%2B%29%29) to create the submodule:

```lisp
#lang racket/base
;;; avl_tree.rkt

(provide (all-defined-out))
(module+ test (require rackunit))

(define (is-tree? tree)
  ; does whatever)
  
  ; so on with other code
  )

(module+ test
  (define some-tree '(5 (1 null null) (9 (6 null null) (10 null null))))
  (check-pred is-tree? some-tree))
```

Comment: You can also provide multiple identifiers at once, btw. `(provide a b c)`. And then there's `contract-out`. `all-defined-out` isn't used all that much in my experience